# Hexadecimal values as Strings C

Tags: c, assembly, hex, endianness

I'm doing an essay for my university and have run into some confusion.

```
int main(void) {
unsigned int i = 0x00646c72;
printf("H%x Wo%s\n", 57616, (char *) &i);
}
```

Basically in a little endian arquitecture this prints out: He110 World

I have to tell what would this print if this piece of code was executed by a Big Endian arquitecture.

So far what I know:

'H', space, 'W' and 'o' would remain where they are because of being a string literal in 8-bit representation.

The value 57616 in base 16 is e110. This in my knowledge should be stored in little endian as 10e1, but still it's printed as 'e110', maybe it has to do with how the %x formatter works?

0x00646c72 translates to ASCII as 'dlr' so in little endian it reads 'rld' but in Big Endian it would print 'dlr'. Are this asumptions correct?

Finally in a very related question:

```
#define VGABUF ((void *) 0xb8000)

void begin(void) {
    int *vga = VGABUF;
    *vga = 0x2f4b2f4f;

    while (1)
        continue;
}
```

I'm asked to modify this code (which shows an OK sign with green background) to behave exactly the same in a Big Endian arquitecture.
I'm thinking I should write vga as a string literal but when I tried it, it did not print anything.

Comment: big and little is irrelevant for the 57616, that would be a bug in the compiler if you got a different result.   The second number takes a 32 bit value  and points at its base address as a string.  in little endian the base address is also the address of the least significant byte.   big endian has different variants, but if we assume they are meaning that the base address of the value is the address of the msbyte and as you go sequentially through that number what to you get treating it as a string?

Comment: @old_timer yeah, exactly. What do you get by traversing each byte in that number being treated as a string. That's why I think in Big Endian it would print dlr. And you are right about the 57616, thanks!

Comment: If you are telling us that little endian walks through those bytes in the order 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x00.  Then does that mean big endian would go 0x00, 0x64, 0x6C, 0x72?  In either case do you understand how an ASCII string is terminated in C?

Comment: About the VGA subquestion: on x86 that C source will write memory bytes `4F 2F 4B 2F`  = `'O' <colours> 'K' <colours>` bytes. On big endian CPU the address is same value `0xB8000`, and `int` value is the same `0x2f4b2f4f`, stored as `int`, so the bytes order in memory will be reversed to `2F 4B 2F 4F`. If the VGA card would be same piece of HW, that would look as `//` on dark red background, first slash in bright cyan, second in bright white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The value 57616 in base 16 is e110. This in my knowledge should be
>   stored in little endian as 10e1, but still it's printed as 'e110',
>   maybe it has to do with how the %x formatter works?

correct, how it's printed has nothing to do with endianess, this will not change on a big endian machine.

> 0x00646c72 translates to ASCII as 'dlr' so in little endian it reads
>   'rld' but in Big Endian it would print 'dlr'. Are this asumptions
>   correct?

you forgot the 0x00 at the beginning. casted to (char *) this is "rld" + terminating 0.
if you have big endian, you will get 0, 0x64, 0x6c, 0x72, the terminating 0 will be the first char, and the string printed will be empty

so the result will be "he110 wo\n"